# VScode C/C++ formatting failed

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, clang-format

I'm on windows 10, It used to work before i don't know why it stopped working, it gives the error message "Formatting failed. See the output window for details." refer to [image]

I've looked for a solution online but what I've found is people saying to use a different extension rather than the default c/c++ formatter which i really don't want to do, why ? it changes my code theme

i just want this fixed i don't want a replacement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! just updated to the pre-release version of the c/c++ extension and it worked like a charm, you can update it back later :)